# JQuery animate() - stopping all animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a question regarding the stopping of more than one animation, I have some pseudo code code below to show my situation:

**CSS**

```
#aDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("gfx/nyancat.png");
    width: 46px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 55%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
    function doAnimate(aDiv)
    {
    $(aDiv).animate({   //do stuff for first animation
                            height: (H*2)+"px",
                            width:  (W*2)+"px",
                            left: "-="+(W*0.5)+"px",
                            top: "-="+(W*0.5)+"px",
                            opacity: 1

                }, 500 , "linear", function()
{ $(aDiv).animate( //do stuff for second animation
                {
                        height: H+"px",
                        width:  W+"px",
                        left: "+="+(W*0.5)+"px",
                        top: "+="+(H*0.5)+"px",
                        opacity: 0.01

                }, 500, function()
                        {   //call itself
                            doAnimate( aDiv );
                        }
                    );
                }
        );
}

//somewhere else in the code
doAnimate(aDiv);
```

When I call the `stop()` function on the `aDiv ( $(aDiv).stop() )`, does this stop both animations? The reason I'm asking is because that I have an animating div that is called upon window load, but upon calling stop and then restarting the animation - the animation doesn't run as it previously did so  I have to refresh the page. Thanks

edit: [fiddle added](http://jsfiddle.net/84x55e07)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `.finish()` or `.stop(true, true);`: http://api.jquery.com/finish/

Comment: create a fiddle please http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry, my apologies - http://jsfiddle.net/84x55e07/

Answer (score 0):

Just using .stop() fulfils my requirement. I'm using JQuery 1.7 so the .finish() functionality isn't available to me. For my problem, changing the background size css value from auto to the original value (55% in my case) seemed to have fixed it.